# About length track measurement - Altium

Tags: altium, measurement

Hi everyone one more time, I have a silly question about trace length measurement on Altium. I was using the PCB tab to measure the length of the traces (on mm). Measuring PCIE_REFCLK_P on the tab de value is 14.072.

[image]

But I realized that If I use Reports>Measure selected objects I see this:

[image]

The measurement is almost 4 mm less, which is the good measurement or the measurement I should to use? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is your question the difference between `mm` and `mil`? If so, because the USA insists on using nonsense units, we're stuck with a bastardisation of metric and imperial: the `mil`! One `mil` is 1000th of an inch, so your numbers are the same.

Comment: No, Is that not the question, and not the same numbers. On PCB tab PCIE_REFCLK_P length is 14.072 as "Routed". Using Reports > Measure select objects  the length is 10.741 mm.

Comment: Got it, that needed clarifying :)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I´m going to edit the post.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I don't recommend putting vias that large over SMT pads that small. Solder will wick through the via barrel and will not flow properly around the component leads, causing a poor (or nonexistent) joint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Net length takes vias in account.

Via length is equal to PCB thickness according to ALtium.

Net Length = Distance measured (with Reports>Measure) + Number of vias * PCB thickness

Comment: Thank you so much! I was afraid because I have used the Net Routed Value.